# OpenJdk Unrecognized option: --list-modules

Tags: java

I'm trying to print a list of all java modules in my JDK bin folder using a command: `java --list-modules`. I'm following the directions on [this page](https://justinmahar.github.io/easyjre/), which is an online tool to create a JRE from OpenJdk on Windows 10. Below is what happened:

> C:\Users\myComputer\Documents\java-se-8u41-ri\bin>.\java --list-modules
>
> Unrecognized option: --list-modules
>
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I searched online [here](http://www.herongyang.com/Java-Tools/java-Option-list-modules-in-JDK.html) for this command and it appears I'm using it correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found over on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267955/finding-the-jre-on-windows) that there is a JRE folder in the JDK main directory so it may not be necessary to create a JRE at all.

Comment: Citing from the linked page: "Starting with JDK 9 and up..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the path you call Java in version 8, modules are available from version 9

> C:\Users\myComputer\Documents\java-se-**8u41**-ri\bin>.\java --list-modules